# How to create fixed table headers using pivottable.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, pivottable.js

I am using a JavaScript plugin ([pivottable.js](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable)) to create pivot tables to display large data on a django site.  I want to add a fixed/sticky table head that stays at the top of my `div` while I scroll down.

Due to the creation of the tables in the JavaScript I cannot easily select the pivot table headers.

Does anyone know of anyway they have accomplished this in the past? A large percentage of my users use IE so it is critical it works on that as well.

Comment: I am using pivottable.js.org/examples to create my pivot table, due to how the table is created in the javascript theres no element that i can select that will embody the whole header therefore I have no way to select the data. If anyone has any solutions for this that would help a lot

Comment: Did you finally find a reliable solution to this?? I'm on my way of doing this. If I get to any solution I'll share it with you as soon as I can. Related [issue here](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/issues/485)

Answer (score 0):

floatThead is what you need to look at http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/

According to its website:

> `jquery.floatThead` is a floating/locked/sticky/fixed table header plugin that requires no special CSS and supports window and overflow scrolling.

Comment: I am using https://pivottable.js.org/examples/ to create my pivot table, due to how the table is created theres no element that i can select that will embody the whole header therefore I have no way to select the data.

Comment: Using 'floatThead' makes problems for the columns width. the width from the tbody is being different from thead.